# Requirement to save item prior to obtaining REST token in compose results in empty draft item

Tags: outlook-addin

O365 returns the following error when our app is trying to obtain REST token in Compose:

Request:

```
Office.initialize = 
    () => Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, 
    res => console.log(res));
```

Response:

```
{
  "name": "CanOnlyGetTokenForSavedItem",
  "message": "The token can't be retrieved until the item is saved.",
  "code": 9029
}
```

The solution is to save the item using Office API:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(
  function callback(result) {
    // Process the result
  });
```

We confirmed that this approach works, HOWEVER, it will also leave an empty message in the Drafts folder if user chooses later to abandon what the user is doing with the message / compose app.

I think this should be handled by Outlook, not by the app, and Outlook should remove the item if the message is abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

For Outlook, this is a draft. This behavior is expected, even with Outlook auto-save option, the message gets saved in drafts folder. 
The user has to explicitly delete it from drafts folder.

Outlook will not voluntarily, delete a message saved by user/add-in, because it will be data loss(if Outlook does so).

But if you are saving a message and you are sure it can be deleted then you can do so using EWS/REST.

Comment: We are having a related issue.  We implemented the 'saveAsync' call on load.  If the user re-opens the app, with the same draft message that was first saved by the saveAsync call, the second saveAsync call takes a long time to execute and then fails.

Comment: Can you share the host info(Outlook Windows/Web/Mac/iOS/Android) and the error which you get?

Comment: It will better if you ask this as a separate question, others will be able to help as well.